# Errores en los if del método AlturaArbol Y Hoja...Arbol Binario

Tags: java

```
public class TadArbolBinario {

    int dato;
    TadArbolBinario izq;
    TadArbolBinario der;
    Nodo raiz;
    TadArbolBinario p;

    public TadArbolBinario() {
        this.dato = 0;
        this.izq = null;
        this.der = null;
        raiz = null;
    }

    public boolean EstaVacio() {
        if (this.dato == 0 && this.izq == null && this.der == null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    public void InsertarNodo(int dato) {
        if (this.EstaVacio()) {
            this.dato = dato;
            this.izq = new TadArbolBinario();
            this.der = new TadArbolBinario();
        } else {
            if (dato < this.dato) {
                this.izq.InsertarNodo(dato);
            } else {
                this.der.InsertarNodo(dato);
            }
        }
    }

    void Inorden(TadArbolBinario raiz) {
        if (!raiz.EstaVacio()) {
            Inorden(raiz.izq);
            System.out.println(raiz.dato);
            Inorden(raiz.der);
        }
    }

    void Postorden(TadArbolBinario raiz) {
        if (!raiz.EstaVacio()) {
            Postorden(raiz.izq);
            Postorden(raiz.der);
            System.out.println(raiz.dato);

        }
    }

    void PreOrden(TadArbolBinario raiz) {
        if (!raiz.EstaVacio()) {
            System.out.println(raiz.dato);
            PreOrden(raiz.izq);
            PreOrden(raiz.der);
        }
    }

    void MostrarArbol(TadArbolBinario raiz) {
        if (raiz != null) {
            MostrarArbol(raiz.izq);
            System.out.println(raiz.dato);
            MostrarArbol(raiz.der);
        }

    }

    boolean Vacio(TadArbolBinario arbol) {
        if (arbol == null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    TadArbolBinario BuscarNodo(TadArbolBinario arbol, int dato) {
        if (Vacio(arbol)) {
            return null;
        }
        if (arbol.dato < dato) {
            if (Vacio(arbol.der)) {
                System.out.println("El número no está en el árbol " + dato);
            }
            BuscarNodo(arbol.der, dato);
        } else if (arbol.dato > dato) {
            if (Vacio(arbol.izq)) {
                System.out.println("El número  no está en el árbol " + dato);
            } else {
                BuscarNodo(arbol.izq, dato);
            }
        }
        if (arbol.dato == dato) {
            System.out.println("El número está en el árbol " + dato);
        }
        return null;
    }

    void alturaArbol (TadArbolBinario raiz, int altura){
        altura=0;
        AlturaArbol(raiz, 0, altura);
    }
     int Hoja(TadArbolBinario raiz){
        if( !raiz.der && !raiz.izq){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }

    void AlturaArbol (TadArbolBinario raiz, int dato, int altura){
        if(raiz.izq){
            AlturaArbol(raiz.izq, dato+1, altura);
        }
        if(raiz.der){
            AlturaArbol(raiz.der, dato+1, altura);
        }
        if(Hoja(raiz) && dato>altura){
            altura=dato;
        }
    }
```

¿Me pueden ayudar con esto? Declaré esos dos metodos que mencioné en el título y me sale error en los if y no entiendo el porqué.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las condiciones de un `if` deben devolver un resultado de tipo `boolean`, y varios de tus `if` no lo hacen.
Por ejemplo `if(raiz.izq)` devuelve un objeto de tipo `TadArbolBinario`. Entiendo que intentas comprobar si `raiz.izq` tiene valor, ¿no? En ese caso deberías cambiar a `if (raiz.izq!=null)`.

Lo mismo pasa en otros `if` que tienes, como `if(raiz.der)`